# Can hackers access Firefoxs login storage through the internet?

Tags: authentication, firefox, storage

Is it possible for hackers to access my Firefox browsers login storage through the internet? For instance if I visit a malicious website?

Answer (score 2):

The answer, according to me would be yes in cases such as:

1. Website is able to execute code on your machine and exploit a vulnerability. **In general if an attacker can execute code on your machine it doesn't remain your (secure) machine anymore.**
2. You are fooled into entering password on the wrong website using the browser password store.
3. Finally, vulnerabilities in the browsers password store mechanism itself will lead to access of stored credentials. Refer to:

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/firefox-master-password-system-has-been-poorly-secured-for-the-past-9-years/

https://www.threatcare.com/password-manager-vulnerability/

Hope this helps.